# How to run reset_db from django-extensions on Heroku ? Fails with: "User does not have CONNECT privilege."

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-extensions

I can do database operations like `heroku run python manage.py migrate` normally, but `reset_db` fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/utils.py", line 58, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/reset_db.py", line 145, in handle
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  permission denied for database "template1"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

I am using `dj_database_url.config` as mentioned at: https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started/blob/33fafbd40ff5532def4ce7b3d0ebc1c7e34a0be7/gettingstarted/settings.py#L115

My full project: https://github.com/cirosantilli/free-books-django-raw/tree/1fd154df716e06e02a5a3afa299a89fe5513a112

On the issue tracker: https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/issues/909

Tested on Django 1.9.6, django-extensions 1.6.7.

Goal: clear up the Heroku database, and then run a command that populates it with my modified test dataset. The Heroku website is currently just a way to show an idea to others, the data there can be thrown away.

Comment: How are you running this? You shouldn't try and connect your local project to the Heroku db; instead run your commands via the server, using `heroku run`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am running `heroku run python manage.py reset_db`, I want to reset and regenerate some modified test data on a Heruku throw-away demo to show it to other people without them having to download my repo.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `reset_db` command - it executes both a "drop" and "create", which I suspect don't quite work with the permissions Heroku grants. Better is to use the built-in Heroku command `pg:reset`. For example: `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL`. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-reset for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew about those commands, but I wish there was a more portable DB independent method that I can run either locally or on Heroku.

Comment: I understand... the core problem is that the DB is in a shared instance on Heroku, so the permissions get locked down. Another thing to try, maybe - write your own management command, iterating over installed apps and calling "migration [app] zero". Long shot (e.g., non-reversible migrations), but might be possible.